How to put the node after the futuring assigned node in the foreach loop?
English is not my native language; please excuse typing errors.
I'm not very sure that the title is proper in my case, but I have paid my best effort.
I have drawn the tikzpicture as below, but it remains some drawbacks as the arrow shows:
In the foreach loop it's difficult for me to put the dashed line below the layer of node with draw=white.

Here below is my MWE:
\documentclass[border=8pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xfp}
\newcommand*{\drawpentagon}[1]{%
    \draw ({-#1*sin(18)},{#1*cos(18)}) --  (0,0) -- (#1,0);
    \ifnum#1=0
        \node [ circle, fill = white, draw , label={[yshift=-3pt]below:{\textbf{1}}}] {};
    \else
        \foreach \i in {1,...,#1}
            {
            \ifodd \i
                \node [ circle, fill = white, draw ] (a) {};
                \node [ circle, draw, fill, xshift = \i*1cm ] (b) at (a) {};
                \node [ circle, draw, fill, shift = {({sin(18)*\i*1cm}, {cos(18)*\i*1cm})} ] (c) at (b) {};
                \node [ circle, draw, fill, shift = {({-cos(36)*\i*1cm}, {sin(36)*\i*1cm})} ] (d) at (c) {};
                \node [ circle, draw, fill, shift = {({-cos(36)*\i*1cm}, {-sin(36)*\i*1cm})} ] (e) at (d) {};
                \draw (b) -- (c) -- (d) -- (e);
            \else
                \node [ circle, draw ] (a) {};
                \node [ circle, draw, fill = white, xshift = \i*1cm ] (b) at (a) {};
                \node [ circle, draw, fill = white, shift = {({sin(18)*\i*1cm}, {cos(18)*\i*1cm})} ] (c) at (b) {};
                \node [ circle, draw, fill = white, shift = {({-cos(36)*\i*1cm}, {sin(36)*\i*1cm})} ] (d) at (c) {};
                \node [ circle, draw, fill = white, shift = {({-cos(36)*\i*1cm}, {-sin(36)*\i*1cm})} ] (e) at (d) {};
                \draw (b) -- (c) -- (d) -- (e);
            \fi
            }
            \draw [ dashed ] (a) -- (d);
            \draw [ dashed ] (a) -- (c);
            \node[label=below:{\textbf{\fpeval{{#1}*4+1}}}] at (#1/2,-3pt) {};
    \fi
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{scope}
            \drawpentagon{0}
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}[xshift=3cm]
            \drawpentagon{1}
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}[xshift=7cm]
            \drawpentagon{2}
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}[xshift=12cm]
            \drawpentagon{3}
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

The \draw [ dashed ] (a) -- (d); and \draw [ dashed ] (a) -- (c); need the name of last-updated node in the \foreach loop process, it acted as a dilemma....
Again please forgive me for my poor description in English. I hope that I have clearified it.

If I understand your code idea correctly, you could try to use layers and draw the dashed lines in a layer, which is drawn first, hence drawn over by the other layers. // Using the background library would do as well: https://tikz.dev/library-backgrounds#autosec-5018

I like generalized solution. The following two commands will draw any polygon with rp sides ≥ 2 corners/edges and rp side length. Their mandatory argment specifies the number of “levels”.

\tikzRepPolyA will draw real edges between the nodes which would allow , with further costumization, the individual styling of each edge. This does not need the white circles to be filled. This would also fancy things like dash expand off.
\tikzRepPolyB will first draw the (partial) polygons and then draw nodes on top of it. This requires fill=white for the white nodes.

Code
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\tikzset{
  @every rp/.code=\edef\rpSides{\pgfinteval{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/rp sides}-2}}\pgfmathsetmacro\rpAngle{360/(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/rp sides})},
  @every rp/.append style={local bounding box=rpbox, x=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/rp side length}, y=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/rp side length}},
  rp sides/.initial=5, rp side length/.initial=+7mm,
  rp node/.style={shape=circle, draw, inner sep=+0pt, minimum size=+1.3ex, rp node \pgfintmod{#1}{2}},
  rp node 0/.code=, rp node 1/.style=fill,
  rp edge/.style=draw, rp edge in/.style={rp edge, dashed}, rp edge out/.style={rp edge},
  rp legend/.style={below, at=(rpbox.south), node font=\bfseries}}

% Nodes with edges between them
\newcommand*\tikzRepPolyA[2][]{% #2 is an integer number
\path[#1,@every rp]
  node[rp node=0, alias/.list={rp-0, rp-..., rp-\rpSides}](rp){}
  \ifnum#2>0 foreach \rpR in {1,...,#2}{
    (rp) foreach \rpS in {0,...,\rpSides}{
      ++(\rpS*\rpAngle:\rpR) node[rp node=\rpR](rp-\rpS'){}
      edge[rp edge \if\ifnum\rpS>0 1\fi\ifnum\rpS<\rpSides\space 1\fi in\else out\fi] (rp-\rpS)
    \ifnum\rpS>0 edge[rp edge out] (rp-\pgfinteval{\rpS-1}')\fi
    node also[alias=rp-\rpS](rp-\rpS')}
  } \fi node[rp legend]{\inteval{1+#2*(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/rp sides}-1)}};}

% Lines with nodes on top
\newcommand*\tikzRepPolyB[2][]{% #2 is an integer number
\path[rp node 0/.style={fill=white},#1,@every rp,rp edge out]
  \ifnum#2>0
    (0,0) foreach \rpS in {0, ..., \rpSides}{-- ++(\rpS*\rpAngle:#2)
      \if\ifnum\rpS>0 1\fi\ifnum\rpS<\rpSides\space 1\fi edge[rp edge in, draw] (0,0) \fi } -- cycle
    foreach \rpR in {1, ..., \pgfinteval{#2-1}}{
      (0:\rpR) foreach \rpS in {1, ..., \rpSides}{-- ++(\rpS*\rpAngle:\rpR)}}
    foreach \rpR in {1, ..., #2}{
      (0,0) foreach \rpS in {0, ..., \rpSides}{++(\rpS*\rpAngle:\rpR) node[rp node=\rpR]{}}}
  \fi
  (0,0)node[rp node=0]{} node[rp legend]{\pgfinteval{1+#2*(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/rp sides}-1)}};}

\begin{document}
\foreach \tikzRepPoly in {\tikzRepPolyA, \tikzRepPolyB}
  \tikz[column sep=1cm, row sep=5mm, column 4/.append style={rp side length=2/3*7mm}]
    \matrix[rp sides=\inteval{\pgfmatrixcurrentrow+1}]{
      \tikzRepPoly{0} \pgfmatrixnextcell \tikzRepPoly{1} \pgfmatrixnextcell \tikzRepPoly{2} \pgfmatrixnextcell \tikzRepPoly{3} \\
      \tikzRepPoly{0} \pgfmatrixnextcell \tikzRepPoly{1} \pgfmatrixnextcell \tikzRepPoly{2} \pgfmatrixnextcell \tikzRepPoly{3} \\
      \tikzRepPoly{0} \pgfmatrixnextcell \tikzRepPoly{1} \pgfmatrixnextcell \tikzRepPoly{2} \pgfmatrixnextcell \tikzRepPoly{3} \\
      \tikzRepPoly{0} \pgfmatrixnextcell \tikzRepPoly{1} \pgfmatrixnextcell \tikzRepPoly{2} \pgfmatrixnextcell \tikzRepPoly{3} \\
      \tikzRepPoly{0} \pgfmatrixnextcell \tikzRepPoly{1} \pgfmatrixnextcell \tikzRepPoly{2} \pgfmatrixnextcell \tikzRepPoly{3} \\
    };
\end{document}

Output


Thanks to @MS-SPO's hint, just to put the following in on background layer scope to draw at the bottom layer.
\draw [ dashed ] (a) -- (d);
\draw [ dashed ] (a) -- (c);

With the follow, it can be fixed!
\documentclass[border=8pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usepackage{xfp}
\newcommand*{\drawpentagon}[1]{%
    \draw ({-#1*sin(18)},{#1*cos(18)}) --  (0,0) -- (#1,0);
    \ifnum#1=0
        \node [ circle, fill = white, draw , label={[yshift=-3pt]below:{\textbf{1}}}] {};
    \else
        \foreach \i in {1,...,#1}
            {
            \ifodd \i
                \node [ circle, fill = white, draw ] (a) {};
                \node [ circle, draw, fill, xshift = \i*1cm ] (b) at (a) {};
                \node [ circle, draw, fill, shift = {({sin(18)*\i*1cm}, {cos(18)*\i*1cm})} ] (c) at (b) {};
                \node [ circle, draw, fill, shift = {({-cos(36)*\i*1cm}, {sin(36)*\i*1cm})} ] (d) at (c) {};
                \node [ circle, draw, fill, shift = {({-cos(36)*\i*1cm}, {-sin(36)*\i*1cm})} ] (e) at (d) {};
                \draw (b) -- (c) -- (d) -- (e);
            \else
                \node [ circle, draw ] (a) {};
                \node [ circle, draw, fill = white, xshift = \i*1cm ] (b) at (a) {};
                \node [ circle, draw, fill = white, shift = {({sin(18)*\i*1cm}, {cos(18)*\i*1cm})} ] (c) at (b) {};
                \node [ circle, draw, fill = white, shift = {({-cos(36)*\i*1cm}, {sin(36)*\i*1cm})} ] (d) at (c) {};
                \node [ circle, draw, fill = white, shift = {({-cos(36)*\i*1cm}, {-sin(36)*\i*1cm})} ] (e) at (d) {};
                \draw (b) -- (c) -- (d) -- (e);
            \fi
            }
            \begin{scope}[on background layer]
                \draw [ dashed ] (a) -- (d);
                \draw [ dashed ] (a) -- (c);
            \end{scope}
            \node[label=below:{\textbf{\fpeval{{#1}*4+1}}}] at (#1/2,-3pt) {};
    \fi
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{scope}
            \drawpentagon{3}
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}[xshift=7cm]
            \drawpentagon{4}
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}[xshift=15cm]
            \drawpentagon{5}
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}[xshift=25cm]
            \drawpentagon{6}
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Well done.

As mentioned in the comment by MS-SPO, a solution is to use a layer, for example the background layer. A disadvantage is that in that case, material such as the dashed lines is drawn on the background layer, thus if afterwards other material is added to that layer then that is drawn on top of those dashed lines. Whereas if the pentagonal figure would be drawn without using a layer then material which would be added afterwards on the background layer, would not be drawn on top of the dashed lines.
The solution below does not use a layer. It is not necessary to name the nodes. First, the lines are drawn. Thereafter, the circles are drawn.
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \drawpentagon { m }
  {
    \int_compare:nNnF {#1} = { 0 }
      {
        \draw [ shift = ( 54 \c_colon_str #1 ) , dashed ] ( 234 \c_colon_str #1 ) -- ( 18 \c_colon_str #1 ) ( 234 \c_colon_str #1 ) -- ( 90 \c_colon_str #1 ) ;
        \draw [ shift = ( 54 \c_colon_str #1 ) ] ( 306 \c_colon_str #1 ) -- ( 18 \c_colon_str #1 ) -- ( 90 \c_colon_str #1 ) -- ( 162 \c_colon_str #1 ) -- ( 234 \c_colon_str #1 ) -- cycle ;
        \int_step_inline:nn { #1 - 1 }
          {
            \draw [ shift = ( 54 \c_colon_str ##1 ) ] ( 306 \c_colon_str ##1 ) -- ( 18 \c_colon_str ##1 ) -- ( 90 \c_colon_str ##1 ) -- ( 162 \c_colon_str ##1 ) ;
          }
        \int_step_inline:nn {#1}
          {
            \int_step_inline:nn { 4 }
              {
                \draw [ shift = ( 54 \c_colon_str ##1 ) , fill = \int_if_odd:nTF {##1} { black } { white } ] ( ####1 * 72 - 126 \c_colon_str ##1 ) circle [ radius = 4 pt ] ;
              }
          }
      }
    \draw [ fill = white ] ( 0 , 0 ) circle [ radius = 4 pt ] ;
    \node [ below ] at ( { #1 * sin ( 36 ) } , 0 ) { \int_eval:n { #1 * 4 + 1 } } ;
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
\foreach\n in {0,...,3}{
  \begin{scope}[shift={({(\n^2)*2*sin(36)},0)}]
    \drawpentagon{\n}
  \end{scope}
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


